# Peculiar Wallpaper Behavior

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, desktop-customization

On my XP desktop I had a wallpaper set, let's say `oldWallpaper.jpg`. Now I changed this to `newWallpaper.jpg` .

Whenever the system starts, first it displays the last set wallpaper `oldWallpaper.jpg` and when it is done with its loaded my profile, it then switches to `newWallpaper.jpg`.

So first I see `oldWallpaper.jpg`, then all the launching and loading, then I see the `newWallpaper.jpg`.

What would be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before as well. From what I remember, the first image it was loading was the last used .bmp wallpaper. Did you "Set as Wallpaper" from an internet browser? These are usually applied as .bmp.

I think my workaround was to clear the wallpaper entirely (ie, no wallpaper) and then set the .jpg as the new wallpaper.